How do I run an FTP script through Cypress?
I have an FTP script that needs to be run in the CMD for me to be able to add a file in the website, now my main work is to automate testcases using cypress and a testcase requires me to get a new file so I have to manually run my ftp script in CMD again and again so I was wondering if there is a way to automate that as well.
I tried using some node modules like basic-ftp and ssh2-sftp-client but was not able to get it

Please show the script.

Details are a bit sketchy in my mind, but I see three options:
Run the FTP script as a pre-script
In package.json scripts section add a script with prefix pre and it will run automatically before the Cypress script.
{
  "scripts": {
    "cy:run": "npx cypress run",
    "precy:run": "node run my-ftp-script",
  }
}

Limited in scope, useful mainly for scheduled runs.
Add a task to call your script
Cypress tasks wait for promises to resolve before returning, so promisify() the call to the script and it will be complete before the test runs.
// cypress.config.js

const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        runFtp() {
          const util = require('util');
          const fork = util.promisify(require('child_process').fork);
          return fork(__dirname + '/my-ftp-script.js');
        },
      })
    },
  },
})

For one call per test, set up a global beforeEach(). Otherwise, call the task as required in specific tests.
// cypress/support/e2e.js

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.task('runFtp')
})

Mock with an intercept() instead of using live server
If the file is for the app to fetch(), you can use an intercept to respond with a file from /cypress/fixtures instead of loading via FTP.
This will make the tests run much quicker.
cy.intercept('/users.json', { fixture: 'users.json' })


Its a ftp script not JS and i need it to run in CMD for it to work and the website to be able to fetch data.To run the script all i do is copy the script data and paste it in the cmd of my local system and the file is fetched and i need that process to be automated . Can you suggest something for that.The name of the file is ftp_command.cmd

For cmd try require('child_process').execFile instead of require('child_process').fork.

And read this blog Understanding execFile, spawn, exec, and fork in Node.js
